# talend , mongoDB connection

Tags: talend

I am facing a problem with mongo DB connection.

I have succefully imported tMongo components it to my Talend Open Studio 5.1.1 and by copying the mongo 1.3.jar file to lib/java folder, my Mongo DB jobs are running successfully, but the problem is even if I provide some fake server path(IP) and fake port for mongoDB, my job is running without an error and it is giving me 1 row with no data. and same goes with right IP and port.

How do I resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the connection is not working. As you must be knowing, mongoDB checks that the connection is actually working or not when you perform a query on it.
(Yeah, it doesn't check for a successful connection when you just connect to it ).

I would suggest to instead add the mongoDB components present in Talend for Big Data by following the steps below:
Components provided for MongoDB are :
tMongoDBInput, tMongoDBOutput, tMongoDBConnection etc.

1. Or you can Download the components from http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/ and search for Mongo instead of using Talend Big Data. But I would suggest use Talend for big Data for it.
2. The components will be zipped format , Unzip the same. In Talend Big data you will find the components in Component folder.
3. Copy these Unzipped Components to the installation Path of TOS.
   C:TalendTOS_DI-Win32-r84309V5.1.1pluginsorg.talend.designer.components.localprovider_5.1.1.r84309components
4. Copy the mongo-1.3.jar file in the component folder into the C:TalendTOS_DI-Win32-r84309-V5.1.1libjava
   In many systems you might not be able to see this file then go with ADMINISTRATOR priviliges.
5. optional for few systems——>>> Inside index.xml add 



   save index.xml
6. Restart TOS

Then you will be able to use them as normal components.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, i got the mongodb components and configured in my machine. but mongodb components are very old version. is there any updated versions available in market?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Job running without any error could be due to the connection / meta-data you have used for the Mongo Connector. It doesn't is not possible for the job to run without any error even after giving fakepath.

I guess you might configured (re-modified) the repository connection but using a built-in meta data for component.