# import Data from Excel to MongoDB in Talend

Tags: mongodb, esb, talend, talend-mdm

I'm using Talend ESB tool.Is it possible to copy data from "excel to mongodb" and "MySQL to mongodb" ? If it is yes, how to create the jobs? OR else any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have you need to import MongoDB component in Talend.

Tutorial to Import : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182836/talend-mongodb-connection)

After you need a job that do :

tFileInputExcel  -> tMap -> TMongoDBOutput

And a second :

tMySQLInput -> tMap -> TMongoDBOutput

You need to configure MySQL parameter and TmongoDB parameter in order to have a successful connection.

Comment: thanks a lot & i will try to create the jobs with mongodb component.

Comment: In my tMongoDBOutput have only 'use existing connection' option & it is empty in Basic setting. how to cofigure the connection manually?

Comment: You need to create two Db Connection (right click) in the metadata menu at the left of Talend