# Regarding Talend open studio how to add mongo connections where can i get those connections and jars

Tags: mongodb, talend

I am trying to Import the CSV file into Mongodb Through Talend open studio when iam searching in palette iam not finding any mongodb connections so how to import the jars and where can get those jars ..so please explain me process

1) I need these connections in Talend how to add those connectionstMongoDBInput
2) tMongoDBOutput
3) tMongoDBConnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDb component are only in "talend for Big Data" version.

Or

You can download them and add them to "Talend for data integration" version for example. This post will help you if you choose that option : [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182836/talend-mongodb-connection)